# Applying thinset to concrete floor

Tags: concrete

I am planning to install ceramic tiles with a "Warmup" heating element beneath them. My first step is to install 1/4" insulation boards on the concrete floor using non-modified thin-set. The floor previously was covered with "peel and stick" tiles that were installed in the late 70s. When I removed the tiles, the glue residue is still evident (the cement floor is tacky when you walk on it). My questions are:
- must I remove the remaining adhesive from the floor. If so, how do I best do this?
- Is there a type of thin-set that will work well without removing the adhesive?

Comment: Do you have a picture?  And how thick is the adhesive?

Comment: I have a picture but as a first-time user, I am uncertain how to attach it to my original question (or this response!). The adhesive certainly is not thick, but is tacky to the touch. I just returned from the hardware store and they suggested a product called Circa 1850 bio degluer. After applying, the glue can be scrapped off. I am investigating this option further to better understand how this product works